# Mesh disappears when using boolean modifier

Tags: modifiers

Mesh disappears when trying to boolean it with a text, some text font work but this one doesn't i really like this one. Text here is already converted into mesh.

[image]

Comment: please provide your blend file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your normals are facing in the wrong direction?

Comment: yess, thank you, i flipped the normals and it worked :)

Comment: and recalculating normals :)

Comment: Great, you are welcome! :)